# Ember.js typeKey on save

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I'm trying to make an Contact List example app with ember.js but i'm stuck when i try to save a new 'Contact'.

I have this Model:

```
Agenda.Contact = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string')
});
```

With this Controller:

```
    Agenda.NewContactController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    actions: {
        save: function(){

            var newContact = this.store.createRecord('contact', {
                name: this.get('name')
            });

            newContact.save();
            this.transitionToRoute('contacts');
        }
    }
});
```

With this routes:

```
Agenda.Router.map(function(){
    this.resource("contacts", {path: '/'});
    this.resource("about");
    this.resource("new-contact");
});

Agenda.ContactsRoute= Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(){
        return this.store.find("contact");
    }
});
```

When i try to call 'save' action this error appear: 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'typeKey' of undefined' on ember-data modelFor function. 
What have I done wrong?

Comment: You don't seem to be using Ember CLI. So that I can help: which versions of Ember and Ember Data are you using?

Comment: And the full stacktrace...